# Verificar se arquivo existe usando Javascript ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso verificar usando Javascript ou jQuery que um arquivo existe ?

**OBS**: Abri a pergunta e já respondi.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: @bigown Tem na resposta abaixo.

Comment: :D é que eu analisei na fila, não mostrava nada

Comment: Existe no servidor ou no computador de quem está vendo a página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaixo estão os meios que eu encontrei.

## Javascript

```
function verificaUrl(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}
```

## jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.exemplo.com.br/arquivo.txt',
    type:'HEAD',
    success: function() {
        //arquivo existe
    }
    error: function() {
        //arquivo não existe
    },
 });
```

Comment: essa é a resposta?

Comment: isso verifica uma url e não a existência de um arquivo...