# Verificar existencia de um arquivo - JS

Tags: javascript, validação, redirecionamento

Boa noite

Eu quero saber se um determinado arquivo em um diretório existe ou não usando JS puro, porém nenhuma das Respostas na internet funcionou.

respostas que tentei:

- [Resposta 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82954/verificar-se-arquivo-existe-usando-javascript-ou-jquery)
- [resposta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62457655/13710880)

a resposta 2 retorna esses erros:
[image: erros retornados ao tentar esse metodo]

gostaria de saber como posso verificar se um existe ou não em um diretório usando apenas JS.

Meu código

```js
function abrirPagina(){
    var url = "umcaminhoqualquer/index.html";

    if (validarPagina(url)){
        window.location.href = (url); //redireciona para uma pagina local
    }else{
        alert('pagina ainda não existe');
    }
}

function validarPagina(url){
  //verificar e retornar true caso exista
}
```

desde já agradeço

Comment: para verificar uma "pasta" em um site não tem como... mas para arquivos, você pode usar ajax, e ver se o código retornado é 404 (não encontrado), olhe: [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) , no caso desta api, o código vai ser retornado em status...mais só será o definitivo quando readyState for 4

Comment: ah, e parece que os endeços que você estava tentando eram para o computador, resumindo é impossivel, um js de página web acessar o sistema de arquivos do computador..., oque você pode acessar são apenas outras páginas web, e dependendo da configuração dos servidores, apenas do mesmo site

Comment: se deseja acessar/gerenciar os arquivos do PC com JS recomendo node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade esta certo tanto a resposta1 quanto a resposta 2, provavelmente voce nao esta rodando sua aplicacao em nenhum servidor, e justamente por esse motivo voce tem esse erro, sugiro que voce tente usar algum servidor. Exemplo: NODE

Boa sorte.